# How to Insert User Data from Facebook Canvas using PHP SDK to a Database using SQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, facebook-php-sdk

I’m really hoping someone here will be able to help me as I’ve been stuck on this for 3 days and can not seem to get it to work no matter what I try. :(

I’m making a Facebook canvas game, and I’m trying to write a PHP script that when run, will insert the player’s Facebook User ID into my database, along with a timestamp of when the event took place. I want this to happen every time the script is run, so ideally, if a player activated this script say 5 times, then the database table will record their ID 5 times along with 5 different timestamps.

I’ve tried following the instructions on the Facebook developers site in relation to the PHP SDK, and the Graph API, and I’ve found the answers on here great, I’ve tried every one I’ve seen that relates to my problem but I still haven't been able to get it to work. I think I’m missing something really simple as I’m a beginner at the Facebook SDK and PHP in general.

If I understand correctly, I need to create a GraphAPI session within the PHP code, create a variable linked to $facebook->api('/me'), then request whichever user data I need, and then use an SQL INSERT statement to put the data into the database?

The code I have right now will post the current time into the database, so the connection is working fine, however my attempt at connecting to Facebook is the result of a lot of searching online and doesn’t currently work (not to mention it's really messy!). I really need step by step instructions on what PHP code to put where in order to connect to the GraphAPI, get and post the player’s details to the database.

### PHP code (updated since I first asked the question):

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStream;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient;

use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookPageTabHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookThrottleException;

use Facebook\GraphAlbum;
use Facebook\GraphLocation;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphPage;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphUserPage;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('MYAPPID','MYAPPSECRET');

$helper=new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try
{
$session=$helper->getSession();
} 
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) 
{
  //Handle Error
}
catch(\Exception $ex)
{
  //Handle Error
}

if(!isset($session)) //Redirect to Login Dialog
{ ?>
  <script>
    top.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?php echo 'MYAPPID'; ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo 'https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPPADDRESS'; ?>";
  </script> <?php

 exit();
}

$facebook_data=(new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

$user_info['AccessToken']=$session->getToken();
$user_info['UserID']=$facebook_data->getId();

//Database:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "MYUSERNAME";
$password = "MYPASSWORD";
$dbname = "MYDATABASE";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (facebook_id, entry_timestamp) VALUES ({$user_info['UserID']}, '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I’m using phpMyAdmin (WAMP) on localhost, my php version is 5.6.5, MySQL 5.6.12, and Apache 2.4.12.

I should mention, I have "FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();" included in that code, however this PHP script would only be run at a point late in the game when the player has already been logged in and has given all required permissions, so I'm not sure if it's necessary to perform this check here?

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated! :)

---

### Update:

Hi @Phillip thanks again for your reply, I’ve been trying to work with the code you gave me but it’s still giving me an error, I’m hoping you can help again.

I entered my AppID and Secret next to FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication. And entered my AppID again and my game’s Facebook URL in the script for “if(!isset($session)) //Redirect to Login Dialog”.

After you defined $user_info[‘AccessToken’] and $user_info[‘UserID] I wrote an SQL Insert statement to put UserID into my database because getting a $ variable for “UserID” is what I need, however when I run the PHP page, it just redirects to my game’s home page (to the URL I entered above).

If I understand the code correctly, it’s doing this because it hasn’t got a $session/is not connected to the user’s info on the GraphAPI and thinks that the user is not signed in, so it’s redirecting them to my home page to sign in? Is that correct?

It’s probably best practice but I was wondering is including the redirect necessary, as I’m looking for a PHP script that I can call on to perform the get user’s info + insert it into my database actions at a point in the game when the user will definitely be logged in (ie, the page I’ll be calling this script from is a page that the user will only be able to access after they have signed in and granted permissions, so is it necessary to perform the login check/initiate the FacebookCanvasLoginHelper?) In any case, does the fact that it’s currently redirecting me to my game’s homepage mean that the connection to get the user’s data isn’t successful?

What’s really confusing me is that I’ve been working from Facebook’s FriendSmash example, and they’ve made a GraphAPI connection in that (I think using the Javascript SDK), with that, if I include the .js file at the top of the page, I’m able to write something in HTML like:

```html
<div id="welcome"><p>Player's address: <span class="link"></p>
```

And that will give me an output of “Player’s address: (url to my (currently signed in) facebook account)”. But I can’t use a PHP Insert statement to put the “link” into my database, maybe I’m expecting the variables from the connection made by the Javascript SDK to be used by the PHP SDK too and this isn’t possible, maybe I need to initiate a whole new connection using the PHP SDK to be able to perform an Insert statement with PHP?

I don’t understand why the code you gave me keeps redirecting me to my game’s page and doesn't seem to be making the connection, when I’m already signed in. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here. :s
I really appreciate your help on this! :)

Comment: You're combining two different versions of the PHPH SDK.  $facebook does not exist in your code and isn't generated by the PHP SDK 4.0+.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for replying! I'm afraid the code I have right now is a real mess. :(  What you said about $facebook not existing makes sense, as I've been getting the error "Notice: Undefined variable: facebook in..." whenever I run the page.

Comment: @Phillip if     "$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  $fbid = $user_profile['id'];"       won't work due to $facebook not working with my SDK version, what line of code should I be using to get the user info/create a variable for the user's id? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Phillip I've written an update to my question because it was too long to add in as a comment, thanks again!

Comment: You have to redirect to the OAuth dialog to authenticate with the PHP SDK.  You can authenticate with the JS SDK as well but you won't be able to transfer information to PHP.  In your app settings, under Migrations do you have all 3 options turned `on`?  Also update your code to reflect your changes.

Comment: @Phillip Thanks again for your help, and for explaining the authentication issue. This PHP file I'm working on is to be called/run whenever a specific in-game condition in a .js file is met (I'm currently using AJAX to make this call). I'm able to display the player's UserID on a page by using a HTML span class which calls a variable from a .js file (part of the FriendSmash download which contains a GraphAPI connection to the user's public profile), but I can't work out why the code I have right now won't create a session in PHP.

Comment: @Phillip I checked under Migrations but there are only 2 options: Stream post URL security (OFF), and Enhanced Auth Dialog (ON). Under Advanced I have both "Client OAuth Login" and "Embedded Browser OAuth Login" set to (YES), but I don't have anything entered in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".    Could the fact that I'm using localhost (with an SSL cert) be causing problems with creating the session? Also, my app is still in development mode and isn't live, could that be affecting these operations?

Comment: I reread your comment and I noticed you said this was an AJAX call.  You should only use the login code on your `index.php` file.  AJAX calls should be authenticated in a different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're close, I'll just post what I use.  Make sure you read the docs to make sure you know what's going on.  Also, utilize the autoloader that Facebook provides.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStream;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient;

use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookPageTabHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookThrottleException;

use Facebook\GraphAlbum;
use Facebook\GraphLocation;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphPage;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphUserPage;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID','APP_SECRET');

$helper=new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try
{
  $session=$helper->getSession();
} 
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) 
{
  //Handle Error
}
catch(\Exception $ex)
{
  //Handle Error
}

if(!isset($session)) //Redirect to Login Dialog
{ ?>
  <script>
    top.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?php echo 'APP_ID'; ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo 'https://apps.facebook.com/my_app/'; ?>";
  </script> <?php

  exit();
}

$facebook_data=(new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

$user_info['AccessToken']=$session->getToken();
$user_info['UserID']=$facebook_data->getId();

?>
```